# Laravel Add new Table with migrate

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration

I have created a Laravel project and I added few table with Migrate.
It was working fine. The tables already had data. Now I require another table and I tried to add it with this command:

```
php artisan make:migration create_books_table
```

It is working and add files at \database\migrations....
I then added schema at up() function. But when I run the command,

```
php artisan migrate
```

It is not working , giving error Base table or view already exists.

Please help. I am very new to laravel. Thanks

Migration code..

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateBooksTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('books', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('books');
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please share your migration code?

Comment: Your database already don't have any `books` table or view, right? Looks everything is fine..

Comment: Yeh, no book table. But some other table are there. So it gives the error..

Answer (score 4):

create new folder in "database/migrations/" and use the "path" property on migrate , Once the table is migrated, you can move the migration file back to the usual folder.

```
php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/new folder/
```

Answer (score 3):

Laravel has an own table called migration. It's used to save information about when a table was created so artisan can rollback to another point. If you delete a table manually the entry in the migration table is still there. If you remove all tables in your database and migrate again it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete the existing 'books' table in the database;

The table already exists so it wont get created again.

Or if you donot have too much data in the other tables run

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

This will roll back previous table migrations and re migrate them all